# Instruments: What does this even mean?

Tags: xcode, instruments

[image]

What does this arrow mean? Horrible UI in my opinion.

Comment: Looks like click to hold and drag mouse. Terrible UI indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Means to drag (Drag Gesture) I think